# The shortest Binary sequence to cover Dec numbers 0-99

Tags: binary, sequence

Consider the set of strings S that contains the binary representation of the numbers 0 to 99. What is the shortest string T such that every element of S is a substring of T?

Comment: "The machine does not care about the order of your sequence": What does it care about, if not the order? Also the example doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @sth Your sequence can be something like 101010101111010110001010000000011. If the rigth answer is 111, the machine try to match it. It is like a regex "*111*".

Comment: Do you mean "Consider the set of strings S that contains the binary representation of the numbers 0 to 99. What is the shortest string T such that every element of S is substring of T?"

Comment: Are you asking, "What is the shortest bitstream that contains all binary numbers less than 99?"?

E.g. the shortest bitstream that contains 0, 1, 2, and 3 is "110"

Comment: reessfabricant: Yes! The number "0100" has substrings: "1", "10", "100" and "0".

Comment: reessfabricant: I gave the example that our defintion of substring is the same.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: Yes. Please, have a look at my discussion between rossfabricant. His shorter question is what I meant. I hesitated to write it as a mathematical problem. Hopefully, you can understand it.

Comment: Kjellerstrand has an online De Bruijn generator http://www.hakank.org/comb/debruijn.cgi and I converted a De Bruijn sequence C program to Ruby at http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2009/09/27/a-case-for-using-only-three-different-digits-in-keypad-codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is very similar to the binary [De Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). The algorithm for that problem, which uses [Eulerian cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_cycle), can easily be adapted to solve your problem.

Comment: +1 Very cool :) I was actually looking for some mathematical reprentation for it. How can you get it with computer?

Comment: You'll have to learn some graph theory :) The algorithms are explained in the two pages I linked to.