# Shortest Bit Sequence Logic

Tags: algorithm, bit

I am trying to understand how does the shortest bit sequence work. I mean the logic. I need to create a program for it but don't know actually what is this shortest bit sequence. I tried to google but in vain. I came across this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058447/algorithm-for-shortest-bit-sequence) on SO but I cant understand anything from it. Can anyone explain it to me or guide me somewhere where I can understand the logic behind this?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818847/the-shortest-binary-sequence-to-cover-dec-numbers-0-99

Comment: The shortest bit sequence *for what*? The shortest sequence *period* is the empty sequence. I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: @harold for example the shortest bit sequence for 42 is [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]. I want to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: So, you want to represent some value in base (-2) ?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jan Dvorak pointed out in the comments, it's simply a number written in base `-2`.

Consider your example `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

The exponents of `-2` are the same as for 2, but *with alternating signs*:

```
(-2)^0 =   1
(-2)^1 =  -2
(-2)^2 =   4
(-2)^3 =  -8
(-2)^4 =  16
(-2)^5 = -32
(-2)^6 =  64
 ...
```

In the bit sequence notation lowest exponents come first, that is the order is reversed compared to ordinary binary numbers.

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] = 0 * (-2)^0  +
                        1 * (-2)^1  +
                        1 * (-2)^2  +
                        1 * (-2)^3  +
                        1 * (-2)^4  +
                        1 * (-2)^5  +
                        1 * (-2)^6
```

which gives (from the bottom up)

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] = 64 - 32 + 16 - 8 + 4 - 2 = 42
```

Comment: I am sorry for my benightedness but How can I generate 0111111 from 42 ? just the reverse of what you did here ?

Comment: Initially I would only have a number then from that I will have to generate the bit sequence since the binary of 42 is 101010 I cant relate 0111111 from it.

Comment: This was explained in the [question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13059318/577603) in your original post. Follow the three steps described there and you have your algorithm.

Comment: Can you please give me some other link ? I really cant understand what is explained their.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? I assume you do already know how to convert decimals to ordinary binaries? The identities presented in the linked answer for calculating the "negative binary" and the simplification are a little bit tricky, so be sure to play around with them on paper to see what's going on. If you can give a more concrete explanation of what troubles you, feel free to ask.

Comment: I am a Bigginer so sorry if I sound complete retard somewhere, for starters binary of 14 is 1110 and their its written 0111 (Might be reverse i guess ), 

second is: When you compute this
`2^1 = (-2)^1 + (-2)^2
2^2 = (-2)^2
2^3 = (-2)^3 + (-2)^4`
how to translate it to this `0, 1, 2, 1, 1` and call it negetive binary representation ? it has a 2 in it.

Comment: I know I sound too stupid but i really want to understand this.

Comment: The "negative binary" of step 2 is an _intermediate representation_. It's not really a binary. The problem here is how to convert the odd-exponent digits? How do you represent e.g. the `8` digit when you don't have `2^3`? The idea is to use the next bigger digit (`+16`) and subtract the negative digit from it (`16 + (-8) = 8`). That way you can write your number even with the alternating signs of the powers. Now what if your original binary already had a 1 in the `16` digit? You need to add 16 _twice_, hence the `2` which is not allowed for binaries. Step 3 takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(A):
    n=len(A)
    result=0
    if n==0:
        return -1
    for i in range(n):
        result+=(A[i]*pow(-2,i))
    return result
print solution([1,0,0,1,1])
```